# Does blockchain with proof of stake consensus have special nodes to choose a winner?

Tags: algorithm, blockchain, consensus

Does blockchain with proof of stake consensus have special nodes to choose a winner or does each node solve this task?

I don't know the special nodes choose winner or distributed p2p network blockchain solves this task?

If you have some links on info, I would like to read the info.

Comment: What do you mean by choose a winner?

Comment: The winner is a validator who validates a block.